# Pass multiple JavaScript variables to C# code behind on ASP button click event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm making a form with multiple buttons that gather variable data as the user clicks the buttons. These variables are gathered using javascript and I've set all the buttons to OnClientClick="return false";

This is because I want to avoid the form from re-submitting as it resets the current Bootstrap tab to 1.

How can I pass all the variables that have been gathered using JavaScript to a C# code behind once the user has reached the final tab and pressed the Save button? Thank you in advance (I'm new to all of this).

Here's some of the JavaScript code:

```
 //Variables for different ratings
var TotalRating = 0;
var ResponseRating = 0;
var ConditionRating = 0;
var SafetyRating = 0;
var InformationRating = 0;
var PrivacyRating = 0;
var PestRating = 0;
var FairnessRating = 0;
var Experience = "";
var Recommendation = "";

//STEP 1
//Styling: nothing required yet


//STEP 2
//Styling
$("#btnGood, #btnFair, #btnBad").click(function () {
    $("#Experience").slideUp();
    $("#Recommendation").fadeIn(1000);
});

$('#btnGood').click(function () {
    Experience = "Good";
});

$('#btnFair').click(function () {
    Experience = "Indifferent";
});

$('#btnBad').click(function () {
    Experience = "Bad";
});
```

The idea being that once the user clicks save (on the last tab), that experience variable could be retrieved in the C# code behind and saved to a SQL Server table.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ This is at least a 10  years old question. Go out and learn javascript on your own, forget that WebForms exists. This has been answered many thousands of times

Comment: You should post your code... The idea would be to serialise all the inputted data to submit it. But, I guess no one can tell more than that. You could also look for Ajax... Depending on what you really want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but can you give me a hint please? I saw some info on using hidden controls to store variable values but by the time the user reaches the end of the form, they will have pressed about 50 buttons. Will I have to make a hidden control for each of these button variables or is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object, instead of so many variables, to store the user infos.

Then, when ready to submit, all the collected infos are at the same place, making it easy to send.

```
var userInputs = {
  TotalRating: 0,
  ResponseRating: 0,
  ConditionRating: 0,
  SafetyRating: 0,
  InformationRating: 0,
  PrivacyRating: 0,
  PestRating: 0,
  FairnessRating: 0,
  Experience: "",
  Recommendation: ""
};

//STEP 1
//Styling: nothing required yet


//STEP 2
//Styling
$("#btnGood, #btnFair, #btnBad").click(function () {
    $("#Experience").slideUp();
    $("#Recommendation").fadeIn(1000);
});

$('#btnGood').click(function () {
    userInputs.Experience = "Good";
});

$('#btnFair').click(function () {
    userInputs.Experience = "Indifferent";
});

$('#btnBad').click(function () {
    userInputs.Experience = "Bad";
});
```

Using ajax to send the data avoids the page reload...

```
// The "save" button may look like this
$('#save').on("click",function () {

  $.ajax({
    url:"[your server ressource URL]",
    data:userInputs,
    method:"post",
    success:function(html){
      console.log("Data sent successfully.");
    },
    error:function(request,status,errorThrown){
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

Read more on [Ajax usage](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jquery/ajax.html).

---

**EDIT**

If I can suggest some more:

It could be a good idea to place the values in some data attributes.

```
<button class="Answer" data-objectProperty="Experience" data-userAnswer="Good">Good</button>
```

Doing so, only one event handler is required.

```
$('.Answer').on("click",function (e) {

  // Avoid the form submit.
  e.preventDefault();

  // Grab the value.
  var objProperty = $(this).data("objectProperty");
  var userAnswer = $(this).data("userAnswer");
  userInputs[objProperty] = userAnswer;
});
```

Comment: This is the best way of doing it that I've seen. Thanks!

Comment: I added an additionnal suggestion... To limit the amout of click handlers. ;)